# Error "the constructor HighScore(int,int,String)is undefined" ( game = new HighScore((id, score, user); )

Tags: java, constructor, undefined

when run the code is shown the constructor HighScore(int, int, String)is undefined"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighScore{

    public static HighScore readGameScore(Scanner sc){
        HighScore game;
        String user;
        int id;
        int score;

        System.out.print("Enter game user: ");
        user=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter game ID: ");
        id=sc.nextInt();

        do{
            System.out.print("Enter game score: ");
            score=sc.nextInt();
            if(score<0){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid value. ");
            }
        }while(score<0);
        *game = new HighScore(id, score, user);*
        return game;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        HighScore game;

        System.out.println("Enter your game score info!");
        game = readGameScore(sc);
        System.out.println("You entered: ");
        System.out.println(game);
        }
 }
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Do you understand what a constructor is?

Comment: In Java, you have to provide an explicit implementation for a Constructor that takes arguments.

Comment: Not really so i don't know how to fix the error

Answer (score 1):

So your class has no constructor defined so the compiler produces a default constructor under the hood i.e.

```
public HighScore(){}
```

you need one defined like

```
public HighScore(int id, int score, String user){
......
}
```